# Isn't this sentence apparently misconstructed?

Tags: sentence-construction

I read this sentence in "The Tempest" by William Shakespeare:

> This is no mortal business, nor no sound that the earth owes. I hear it above me.

And it translates to:

> This is not something done by mortals. Nor is it a sound that could come from the normal world.

I want to ask shouldn't there be "a" instead of "no" in the original text. Because "nor" and "no" are both negative and "a" instead of "no" would do much better there at least for me. Am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was 'correct' when Shakespeare wrote it. The rules about 'double negatives' were looser then than they later became. Now, we would write 'Nor a sound ...'. You will find many such 'misconstructions' in Shakespeare and many writers from hundreds of years ago. If you understand the meaning, accept them as they are.